# FCM without Including Server Key

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM as my engine to allow users to send messages to each other.

I send a message by using the following:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
        String userDeviceIdKey = params[0].url;
        String title = params[0].title;
        String body = params[0].body;
        String uniqueID = params[0].uniqueID;

        String authKey = "XXXXXXX";
        String FMCurl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL( FMCurl );
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setUseCaches( false );
            conn.setDoInput( true );
            conn.setDoOutput( true );

            conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "key=" + authKey );
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put( "to", userDeviceIdKey );
            json.put( "priority", "high" );
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            info.put( "title", title );
            info.put( "body", body );
            info.put( "uniqueID", uniqueID );
            info.put( "var1", chatID );
            info.put( "var2", NotMyID );
            info.put( "var3", UID );
            info.put( "NOTIFY_STYLE", "MESSAGE" );
            json.put( "data", info );

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream() );
            wr.write( json.toString() );
            wr.flush();

            conn.getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException | JSONException ignored) {

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

In this way, everything works perfectly and each user gets their messages and the pop up notifications as needed.

Now, in order to avoid displaying my Server Key inside the code I looked that it is possible to do something like this:

```
auth.getAccessToken(  )
```

So the line will look like:

```
conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "key=" + auth.getAccessToken( true ));
```

When I tried to do it, no notification was sent.

How can I solve it without writing my Server Key inside the code itself and actually keep it secret?

Thank you

Comment: There is no secure way to send device to device messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Any time you use the FCM server key in your client-side code, the user who executes that code can take your FCM server key and use it to send any message they want to all of your users.

Comment: So basically FCM is not built for a device to device? No way to overcome this security problem for device-device messages?

Comment: That's indeed correct. The only way to directly deliver messages securely (directly) through FCM is from a trusted environment, where you can use the FCM server key - but others can't.